# SQL How to transform Column into Variable

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

Say I have a table that looks like this

```
Type   Day       Volume
"C1"   Tuesday     10
"C1"   Monday      10
"C2"   Tuesday     10
"C2"   Monday      10
```

What is the most efficient way to transform it into a table which looks like this?

```
Day      C1  C2
Tuesday  10  10
Monday   10  10
```

Ideally I would to do this without any PIVOT function just by using group by.

Thank you for your time and help. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: What is the problem? Seem like you already know pivot and group by.

Comment: I have to create a table where the volume is grouped by the Type but with the type as columns and the days as rows indexes. I am not allowed to use pivot only the group by function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using conditional aggregation:

```
select day, 
       max(volume) filter (where type = 'C1') as c1,
       max(volume) filter (where type = 'C2') as c2
from the_table
group by day;
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using the `tablefunc` extension, I'd write something like:

```
select 
  * from crosstab 
    ('select Day, Type, Volume from my_table order by 1,2') 
    as result (Day text, C1 int, C2 int);
```